# "var_name is not accessed Pylance" is wrong

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylance

For some reason, Pylance gives me many such warnings even though the variables are used!

Here is an example:

```
breach = limits["breach"]
if len(breach) > 0:
    message = str(breach)[1:-1]
```

Here it will say breach is not accessed, even though I'm doing len() on it next row!

[image]

Why can this be happening and how to fix this?

Comment: No such message shows up.

Comment: Cannot reproduce the issue. You can try reinstalling the Pylance extension or switching to a pre-release version.

Comment: If you use `breach` in subsequent code, will this prompt still appear?

Answer (score 0):

You can try reinstalling the Pylance extension or switching to a pre-release version.